# How to connect with sql server using php in xampp

Tags: php, sql, xampp

I have xampp install in my computer and xampp php version is 5.5.15 i want to connect with a sql server (which is also install in my computer sql server 2005) i download php driver and copy paste two php file "php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll" and "php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll" in "C:\xampp\php\ext" folder and format php.ini file extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll and extension="php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll"  my problem is when i am  restart the apache server (from xampp control panel) it's display two error message  one is

httpd.exe error "http.exe error msvcp110.dll is missing from your computer"
another one is 
"xampp error php startup unable to load dynamic library the specific module could not be found"
beside this error i am trying to connect with sql server using code but the code return with undefined sqlsrv_connect function error

My code is simple

```
<?php
$serverName='SANTUNU23-PC\SQLEXPRESS';
$connectioninfo=array ('Database'=>'DB2662_cslBeseElec');
$myuser='santunu23';
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectioninfo);
if($conn)
{
echo 'connection established';
}
else
{
echo 'can not make the connection'; 
die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));
}
?>
```

What to do now?any suggestion My system is windows 7 32bit

Answer (score 1):

You could've googled "msvcp110.dll", then you would know that this file belongs to the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable Package". So download it, install it, try it again.

Comment: i have microsoft visual c++ 2013 redistributable package install in my computer but as your  suggestion  i am going to download and install microsoft visual c++ 2012 redistributable package in my computer

Comment: Yeah, the problem with those c++ redistributable packages is, they are not backwards-compatible so you really need the exact version. Also be sure you install the correct bit-version. If your webserver/PHP is running 32 bit, you'll need the 32-bit version even if your computer is running under 64 bits (since 32bit executables can only load 32bit dlls).

Comment: After install microsoft visual c++ 2012 redisttributable packages it's ok now. Thanks everybody.